# Library reference ../android-support-v7-appcompat could not be found

Tags: android

Library reference ../android-support-v7-appcompat could not be found while impporting new project in android studio

Comment: you can add dependencies compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' in build.gradle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to the Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Try navigate Tools > Android > SDK Manager and see what you have installed. You might be missing the necessary support library. Here is what mine looks like

[image]